# i want to share the score of my html 5 game by facebook and twitter

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I have game which is on html 5. 
All the script in js. 
So i want o fetch the game score result and display in my webpage (php or html tag)
I want to share that score by twitter and facebook.
this is the javascript

I want to display this by php on my webpage. 
I just need to share that js score to facebook and twitter.

thanks

Comment: welcome to SO,please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

### Facebook Sharer

At this link : [Facebook Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button). This app from facebook developers is generating your code to implement on your website to share. For a concrete example, the score page of your html5 game.

### Twitter Sharer

You need to implement this javascript code at the bottom of your body tag :

```
<script>
window.twttr=(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],t=window.twttr||{};if(d.getElementById(id))return t;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);t._e=[];t.ready=function(f){t._e.push(f);};return t;}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

And you need to add this "a" where you want the tweet button to be placed :

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/share">
Tweet
</a>
```

But you can find out more right here : [Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button)